# Using an instance's fields to filter the choices of a manytomany selection in a Django admin view

Tags: django

I have a Django model with a ManyToManyField.

1) When adding a new instance of this model via admin view, I would like to not see the M2M field at all.

2) When editing an existing instance I would like to be able to select multiple options for the M2M field, but display only a subset of the M2M options, depending on another field in the model. Because of the dependence on another field's actual value, I can't just use formfield_for_manytomany

I can do both of the things using a custom ModelForm, but I can't reliably tell whether that form is being used to edit an existing model instance, or if it's being used to create a new instance. Even MyModel.objects.filter(pk=self.instance.pk).exists() in the custom ModelForm doesn't cut it. How can I accomplish this, or just tell whether the form is being displayed in an "add" or an "edit" context?

EDIT: my relevant code is as follows:

models.py

```
class LimitedClassForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LimitedClassForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.instance._adding:
            # Edit form
            clas = self.instance
            sheets_in_course = Sheet.objects.filter(course__pk=clas.course.pk)
            self.Meta.exclude = ['course']
            widget = self.fields['active_sheets'].widget
            sheet_choices = []
            for sheet in sheets_in_course:
                sheet_choices.append((sheet.id, sheet.name))
            widget.choices = sheet_choices
        else:
            # Add form
            self.Meta.exclude = ['active_sheets']
    class Meta:
        exclude = []
```

admin.py

```
class ClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {models.ManyToManyField: {
        'widget': CheckboxSelectMultiple}, }
    form = LimitedClassForm

admin.site.register(Class, ClassAdmin)
```

models.py

```
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Sheet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=getSheetLocation)

class Class(models.model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    active_sheets = models.ManyToManyField(Sheet)
```

You can see that both Sheets and Classes have course fields. You shouldn't be able to put a sheet into active_sheets if the sheet's course doesn't match the class's course.

Comment: for add/edit check do `if form.instance.pk: [edit form] else [add form]`

Comment: you may also show some pieces of your code...

Comment: if form.instance.pk _always_ evaluates to true for me, regardless of which type of form is going to be displayed.